# Отправляется в БД пустой username. PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
// functions.php
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
function createData() {
    global $connection;
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

    $hashFormat = '$2y$07$';
    $salt = 'usesomesillystringforsalt$';
    $hashF_salt = $hashFormat . $salt;
    $password = crypt($password, $hashF_salt);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('$username', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result) {
      die(mysqli_error());
    } else {
      echo "Created";
    }
  }

// create.php
<?php include "functions.php"; ?>
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if($username && $password) {
    createData();
  } else {
    echo "Input can not be blank";
  }
}
```

Comment: прям антипаттерн программирования на пхп.

Comment: вы там определитесь, что пользуете то mysql или mysqli ?

Comment: хахаах, ага. Сейчас поменяю. Думаете в этом ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас и password не передается. Вы же ничего в функцию не передали, она у вас без параметров. Смотрите, функция - это вещь в себе. Абстрактный кусок кода, который работает ровно с тем, что есть внутри нее и никак не взаимодействует с внешним кодом (про ваши глобальные переменные я не говорю, потому, как так делать нельзя). Но если вам нужны внешние переменные в функции, то их надо изначально объявлять в скобках. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:
при объявление следует добавить

```
function createData($username, $password) {
```

и при вызове (нижний кусок кода)

```
createData($username, $password);
```

Таким образом будет осуществлена передача переменных из нижнего кода в верхний.